# "Column 'name' cannot be null"

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

can you help me with my coding problem? I'm very new at backend and I can't solve a problem. I'm trying to send a post request to my API where I'm updating some user info in my sql database.
But I get an error that my variables are Null, why can that happen?
Here's my html code:

```
<script>
    let name = document.getElementById('text1').value
    let school = document.getElementById('text2').value
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        let btn = document.getElementById('btn_save')
        if (!btn) {
            console.error("Button not found!")
        } else {
            btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
                alert('clicked!')

                console.log(name, school)
                let userID = <%= userId %>
                const url = `http://localhost:4050/db/card/${userID}`

                let body = JSON.stringify({
                    "name": `${document.getElementById('text1').value}`,
                    "scnmb": Number(document.getElementById('text2').value)
                })
                console.log(body)

                fetch(url, {
                    mode: 'no-cors',
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    body: body
                })
                    .then(response => {

                        console.log('Success:', response);
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.error('Error:', error);
                    });

            })
        }
    })
</script>
```

And here's my API code:

```
app.post('/db/card/:userId', jsonParser, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const conn = mysql.createConnection({
            host: 'localhost',
            user: 'root',
            database: 'testdb',
            password: ''
        });

        const { name, scnmb } = req.body;
        const userId = req.params.userId;

        conn.connect(err => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                res.status(500).send('Error connecting to database');
            } else {
                console.log('DATABASE ----- CONNECTED SUCCESSFULLY');
            }
        });

        conn.beginTransaction(err => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                res.status(500).send('Error updating user');
            } else {
                const sql1 = 'UPDATE user_info SET name = ?, scnmb = ? WHERE id = ?';

                conn.query(sql1, [name, scnmb, userId], (err) => {
                    if (err) {
                        conn.rollback(() => {
                            console.log(err);
                            res.status(500).send('Error updating user');
                        });
                    } else {
                        conn.commit(err => {
                            if (err) {
                                conn.rollback(() => {
                                    console.log(err);
                                    res.status(500).send('Error updating user');
                                });
                            } else {
                                console.log('User updated successfully');
                                res.send('User updated successfully');
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        res.status(500).send('Database error');
    }
});
```

Sorry for so much code. I've been spending a few days trying to solve this problem but I can't deal with that. I've tried using POSTMAN and everything works fine. Can you help me?

UPDATED: Even if I try using specific values I get the same error. Here's what I have now:

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        let btn = document.getElementById('btn_save')
        if (!btn) {
            console.error("Button not found!")
        } else {
            btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
                console.log('clicked!')

                console.log(name, school)
                let userID = <%= userId %>
                const url = `http://localhost:4050/db/card/${userID}`

                fetch(url, {
                    mode: 'no-cors',
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        "name": 'Nikitosik',
                        "scnmb": 5
                    })
                })
                    .then(response => {

                        console.log('Success:', response);
                    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to below code snippet:

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        document.getElementById('btn_save').addEventListener('click', function () {
            let name = document.getElementById('text1').value;
            let school = document.getElementById('text2').value;

            let userID = <%= userId %>
            const url = `http://localhost:4050/db/card/${userID}`

            let body = JSON.stringify({
                "name": name,
                "scnmb": Number(school)
            });
           
            fetch(url, {
                mode: 'no-cors',
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: body
            })
            .then(response => {
                console.log('Success:', response);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error:', error);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

What is changed: name & school are moved inside the event listner.

Comment: still nothing. Here's what I have in my console:
USearch
content.js:20 Loaded extension.1
card_settings:211 clicked!
card_settings:214 Nikita 5
card_settings:222 {"name":"Nikita","scnmb":5}
card_settings:224          POST http://localhost:4050/db/card/4 500 (Internal Server Error)
(anonymous) @ card_settings:224
card_settings:234 Success: Response {type: 'opaque', url: '', redirected: false, status: 0, ok: false, …}

Comment: Debugger is attached and hit in your backend service ?

Comment: Sorry, I don’t know anything about debugger, I’ve been programming for only about 7 months. I understand that problem is in request, but I don’t have enough knowledge to solve it.